# How to get only the first elements from each items of a list

Tags: python

I have to following list:

```
[[(640, 92, 0.80969274, 0)], [(524, 180, 0.58553714, 1)], [(494, 181, 0.64085102, 2)], [(477, 338, 0.67508131, 3)], [(554, 480, 0.64356369, 4)]]
```

I'm interested only in the first 2 elements in the items, for example:

```
640, 92
524, 180
494, 181
```

I can get them using

```
print list[1][0][0:2]
```

But what I want to do is to take max and mean by column.
First I want to take the max and min for the first column, and then max and min from the second column.

in matlab we can do something like:

```
max(list(:,1));
min(list(:,1));
max(list(:,2));
min(list(:,2)));
```

Is there a way to do this in python without any headache?

Thank you!

Comment: Of course there are pure Python ways of doing this but if you are doing matlab-like operations, you might want to try numpy.

Comment: Why are your tuples wrapped in a list? Like here: `[(640, 92, 0.80969274, 0)]`

Comment: You definitely want Numpy here

Comment: btw: check out the edit re: f-strings. If you are on Python 3.6, you should consider using them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the other answers have pointed out, fundamentally, you are not using a good data structure for your task. If you want to similar functionality to Matlab in Python, you need to use `numpy` and should take a look at `pandas`. Python is a general purpose programming language, so its sequence types like `list` are not really meant to efficiently do the same things as a Matlab mutli-dimensional array (which is what `numpy` gives you). But that being said, there *is* a relatively painless way of doing what you want. It would be made even more painless if instead of using a list of length 1 lists, each containing a tuple that actually holds your data, you just use a *list of tuples*. But, python makes this sort of munging pretty painless:

```
>>> x = [[(640, 92, 0.80969274, 0)], [(524, 180, 0.58553714, 1)], [(494, 181, 0.64085102, 2)], [(477, 338, 0.67508131, 3)], [(554, 480, 0.64356369, 4)]]
>>> extracted = [sub[0:2] for l in x for sub in l]
```

In the list comprehension above, I just iterate over the list, then iterate over the (length one) list wrapping the tuple, then slice the columns I want from the tuple (`sub`).

Now, to do a "transpose" in vanilla python, unpack into `zip`:

```
>>> for col in zip(*extracted):
...     print("Max: {}".format(max(col)))
...     print("Min: {}".format(min(col)))
...
Max: 640
Min: 477
Max: 480
Min: 92
>>>
```

By the way, using Python 3.6 makes things **even more** painless by giving us f-strings!:

```
>>> for col in zip(*extracted):
...     print(f"Max: {max(col)}")
...     print(f"Min: {min(col)}")
...
Max: 640
Min: 477
Max: 480
Min: 92
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a list of lists (of length 1) of tuples, so we have to do just a bit of legwork.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([d[0] for d in data])
df[0].max()
df[1].max()
df[0].mean()
df[0].min()
```

Tons of operations are supported.

Answer (score -1):

```
max([x[0][0] for x in list])
min([x[0][0] for x in list])
```

This takes max and min for the first column. similarly for the second column you can do this :

```
max([x[0][1] for x in list])
min([x[0][1] for x in list])
```